# How could this circuit work with reverse charged C for gate triggering?

Tags: gate-driving

I built the circuit and get a max-measured gate triggering voltage of 0.24 vac against the needed 1.5 V according to the triac's data sheet, and could not make the circuit work. How is it supposed to work anyway with the Neg side of the 47Mf C providing the gate trigger V?

Comment: You're going to have to show us what circuit you're talking about.